# why two images behave differently for same method?

Tags: c++, image

I created win32 application in visual studio 2010 using this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx.
after that I add a cpp file to this project paste a code snippet that I got from graphics tutorial. this code is shown below.

To compile this solution I have to change character set to Use multi byte character set in project properties.

after that I inserted a picture called truck.bmp to the project folder.

when I used this picture

[image]

it gives this error message

> Bitmap not loaded- Ensure the file 'truck.bmp' is present in the project folder
>   because hbitmap is null according to the program.

but when I used this picture

[image]

it loads properly. Program uses LoadImage function to load the images.

I can't understand why these two pictures behaves differently for the same function. can someone explain the reason for that. sorry for the large image in my question

```
/* to demonstrate loading and displaying of bitmaps */
  #include < windows.h >
  LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsgId, WPARAM wParam,
                        LPARAM lParam);

  int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
static char name[]="Bitmap Display";

HWND hWnd;
MSG msg;
WNDCLASS wndClass;
wndClass.style=0;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc=WindowProc;
wndClass.cbClsExtra=0;
wndClass.cbWndExtra=0;
wndClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
wndClass.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndClass.hInstance=hInstance;
wndClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
wndClass.lpszClassName=name;

if(RegisterClass(&wndClass) == 0)
{
   MessageBox(0, "The Window is not registered", "Message", MB_OK);
   return 0;
}

    hWnd=CreateWindow(name, name, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,         CW_USEDEFAULT,  CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if(hWnd==0)
{
   return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }
 msg.wParam;
  }

   LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsgId, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
HBITMAP hbitmap;
BITMAP bitmap;
HDC hdc, hmemdc;

switch(uMsgId)
{
case WM_PAINT:
 PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
 hdc= BeginPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);

 /* loading the bitmap from a BMP file (ensure the file is present under the    project folder) */
 hbitmap= (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "truck.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP, 0,0, LR_LOADFROMFILE    );

 if(hbitmap == NULL)
 {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Bitmap not loaded- Ensure the file 'truck.bmp' is present in the project folder","Error",MB_OK);
 }

 hmemdc= CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
 SelectObject(hmemdc, hbitmap);
 GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);

 /* displaying the bitmap at certain x,y position on the window client area */
 BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth,bitmap.bmHeight, hmemdc,0,0, SRCCOPY);

 /* displaying the bitmap with scaled dimensions at certain x,y position on the window client area */
 StretchBlt(hdc, bitmap.bmWidth+5, 0, bitmap.bmWidth*2,bitmap.bmHeight*2,  hmemdc,0,0, bitmap.bmWidth,bitmap.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);

 DeleteDC(hmemdc);
 DeleteObject(hbitmap);
 EndPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
 return 0;

case WM_DESTROY:
 PostQuitMessage(0);
 return 0;
default:
 return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsgId, wParam, lParam);
}
  }
```

Comment: You posted a PNG and a JPG, but you claim to be loading a BMP. If that’s important, you’ll need to share the actual BMP files you’re using.

Comment: When you tried the 2 images, were they copied to the same folder? Maybe the filenames are incorrect. You're probably only seeing the first name without the extension.

Comment: Try calling `GetLastError()` after the call to `LoadImage` and paste the error code here.

Comment: This won't fix the problem, but don't load the bitmap every paint, it's inefficient. Load it before and store it somewhere.

Comment: I think when I upload them, they convert to that format. I googled for bmp and uses first two pictures for test
https://www.google.lk/search?q=*.bmp&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0zwCUNr9MsforQfk8L2EBg&ved=0CEcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667
I uses the same name in project folder

Comment: The first image result is a larger bitmap than what you show here. Did you resize it? If so, make sure you really saved it in BMP format after resizing. Simply changing the suffix doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with how you saved the first bitmap.  I used your code with some slight modifications to load and display both bitmaps successfully.  I used right-click -> save link as on both images from here: http://newspaper.li/bmp/